# React | why does .map work when .forEach creates a ' Maximum call stack size exceeded' error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ampersand

New to react and playing around with it. Can't see any obvious reason why I'm getting an error using forEach and no error when using map:

Note: I'm using this with ampersand (a backbone-based framework)
Repos = 30 objects, each with 3 properties

```
export default React.createClass({
  mixins: [ampersandReactMixin],
  displayName: 'ReposPage',
  render() {
    const {repos} = this.props

    return (
      <div>        
        {
          repos.forEach((repo) => {

            return (              
              <div key={repo.id}>
                <span>goodbye world</span>
              </div>
            )
          })
        } 
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

Outputs this:

```
Warning: Any use of a keyed object should be wrapped in React.addons.createFragment(object) before being passed as a child.
warning.js:48 Warning: Any use of a keyed object should be wrapped in React.addons.createFragment(object) before being passed as a child.
warning.js:48 Warning: Any use of a keyed object should be wrapped in React.addons.createFragment(object) before being passed as a child.
traverseAllChildren.js:67 
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

vs

```
export default React.createClass({
  mixins: [ampersandReactMixin],
  displayName: 'ReposPage',
  render() {
    const {repos} = this.props

    return (
      <div>        
        {
          repos.map((repo) => {

            return (              
              <div key={repo.id}>
                <span>goodbye world</span>
              </div>
            )
          })
        } 
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

Which works fine.

I assume it has something to do with map returning a new object by... why exactly does that matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`forEach` always returns undefined.

So, your first example is essentially

```
<div>
  { undefined }
</div>
```

React is choking on rendering undefined it appears.

Comment: +1, Example: Let `var array = [1, 2, 3]`. 
`array.forEach((element) => { return element; } )` returns `undefined`, while `array.map((element) => { return element; } )` returns `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: Was totally over complicating this in my mind, so obvious whats happening now. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

[Check the docs on `forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). The function `forEach` will always return `undefined`.

```
repos.forEach((repo) => {
  return (/* ... */);
})
```

Which will result in the following code

```
<div>
  { undefined }
</div>
```

As the error states, `undefined` is not a valid `DOMElement`. For some reason this error triggers a stack overflow.

Just use `map`, it will actually return a new set of objects (based on what you return inside the function).